# Can light transmission through mostly opaque but radio-transparent materials be increased by amplitude modulation?

Tags: optics, visible-light, attenuation

Can a laser modulated at a low frequency (microwave or radio frequency range) be transmitted further through a medium because the laser is modulated at an envelope frequency that the material is more transparent to?  I suspect this probably isn't the case but I thought that it made some conceptual sense.

Comment: Your title says amplitude but your question says frequency.

Comment: I indicated that this was referring the effective frequency of the envelope.   I realize that how can sound confusing.